# @Autowired Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to de-couple dependencies from an existing Spring app by using 
Spring @Bean in the config class, and @Autowired in the class that utilises it.

Below is the main configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example"})
@EnableWebMvc
public class DataLoadConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    ActivitiesFeed activityFeed() {
        HashMap<Integer, Object> temp = new HashMap<Integer, Object>();
        return new ActivitiesFeed(temp);
    }

    ...
```

Here is how the dependency is being used:

```
public class ActivitiesLoad {

    // ADDED
    @Autowired
    ActivitiesFeed activityFeed;

    public ActivitiesLoad(String loadType, int personCode, String outputFilter, int outputNumber) {

        ...

        // REMOVED - this approach didn't throw any errors though
        // HashMap<Integer, Object> temp = new HashMap<Integer, Object>();
        // ActivitiesFeed activityFeed = new ActivitiesFeed(temp);

        // This dependency is now @Autowired in
        feed = activityFeed.getActivities();
        ...
```

But, I'm now getting the following error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/DataLoads] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ac.uk.strath.t4.dataload.pure.activities.ActivitiesLoad.<init>(ActivitiesLoad.java:66)
    at ac.uk.strath.t4.dataload.controller.DataLoadController.pureActivities(DataLoadController.java:149)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    ...
```

See the original intialisation code, this run without any issue so I know the dependency works but wondering whether I've implemented the injection wrong.

By the way, I don't own the ActivitiesFeed source so I cannot attach any @Components like annotation to the class, so have opted to put it into the app config class (DataLoadConfig) as @Bean.

Note: I've also tried putting the ActivitiesLoad constructor code into a run(...) method, just encase it was an issue with the fact I am trying to access a dependency from within the constructor, but it just gave me the same error. Ideally I'd prefer to leave the code within the constructor for now as it's someone else's code and don't want to risk breaking too much at this stage :)

UPDATE

I've tried to add a @PostConstruct method but just the same issue. I then made the activityFeed property private as I'd seen in examples, but same.

```
public class ActivitiesLoad {

    @Autowired
    private ActivitiesFeed activityFeed;

    private String loadType;
    private int personCode;
    private String outputFilter;
    private int outputNumber;

    public ActivitiesLoad(String loadType, int personCode, String outputFilter, int outputNumber) {
        log.debug("Starting pure activities data load");
        this.loadType = loadType;
        this.personCode = personCode;
        this.outputFilter = outputFilter;
        this.outputNumber = outputNumber;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        log.debug("Starting pure activities data load @PostConstruct");
        log.debug(activityFeed); // outputs: null
        ...
```

UPDATE 2

Here I'm leaving the dependency out of the constructor, instead putting it into it's own init method and calling that after creating the ActivityLoad instance. However, I'm still seeing the issue with NullPointerException.

The instantiating of ActivityLoad (now with `init` method that is called after the instance is created):

```
...
ActivitiesLoad activitiesLoad = new ActivitiesLoad();
activitiesLoad.init(loadType, personCode, typeFilter, outputLimit);
...
```

Here is the ActivityLoad class containing the new method

```
@Component
public class ActivitiesLoad {

    @Autowired
    private ActivitiesFeed activityFeed;

    public void init(String loadType, int personCode, String outputFilter, int outputNumber) {
        log.debug(activityFeed); // outputs: null
```

Comment: you are receiving NullPointerException because autowiring happens after constructor

Comment: like @vlad324 has pointed out, you could do the initialization in a `@PostConstruct` method.

Comment: Hi. I've updated my post. The @PostConstruct method is run, but same issue.

Comment: This is happening because the context is not aware of your configuration. Make sure your component is loaded in the context, can you please let us know if you are using a spring boot web app, or a simple application? Is the context loaded in the main app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to keep in mind 2 things.

i)  If you create a class instance by using the `new` keyword , then the specific instance won't be *managed by Spring* , which means it wont autowire the beans you are requesting in the chain. So from the first place , `ActivitiesFeed activityFeed` will be null always inside the `ActivitiesLoad` instances, which are getting spawned by using `new ActivitiesLoad(...)`

ii)  The second point is regarding your update. As proposed by the other answers , you were trying to invoke a method by an injected bean inside the Class Constructor. This is not working in any DI framework , because the constructor is meant to be used only for initializing the field references and not invoking them. That's why you need the `@PostConstruct`, which gets invoked by the Spring Container after the bean initialization / constructor has finished successfully , thus the  bean reference , will get a proper instance.

So this leaves you with 2 possible options:

**a.** Maintain the context , by autowiring the `ActivitiesLoad` properly as Prototype and pass the required state.

**b.** Refactor the `ActivitiesLoad` to do not keep context at all , change the constructor to keep the default one and implement all the logic along with the required params(context) inside this method. Then you can autowire this bean in the controller by just using `@Autowire`

Comment: That totally makes sense, never occurred to me. Thanks for that. I `@Autowired` the ActivitiesLoad (now as a `@Component`) so I'm not instantiating it with `new` anymore, and then called the `init` method I created with the arguments it requires.

Answer (score 1):

`ActivitiesLoad` should be a Spring component to be able to autowire bean in it.
Try to make it a spring component with one of this i.e. `@Component` `@Service`

And you still will need to use `@PostConstruct` as it was designed directly for such cases.

Comment: If ActivitiesLoad has to be a `@Component` then I'd need to remove arguments from the constructor. Same with the `@PostConstruct` method, I wouldn't have the arguments to pass in. Anyway, I tried to remove the arguments anyway so that I could add a post-initialisation method (init) but it just gives me the same error. See UPDATE 2 above.

Comment: If `ActivitiesLoad` is not managed by Spring, Spring will not care about your `@Autowire` annotation, Spring injects dependencies only in beans. If you require parameters to be passed to constructor then you could create `ActivitiesLoad` as `@Bean` in configuration class.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you did not load the component in the context.

Your question is missing some infos, but in case you are running a standalone application or a spring boot web app, you should have a part of logic which explicitly says  "please load DataLoadConfig" in the context.

I will refer to a link to avoid to re-write your code : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_java_based_configuration.htm

the 4th code snippet is what I assume you missing, which actually will cause the issue you are facing. The component is not in the context so when you autowire it you get a nullpointer.

Make sure in you main the component is there via following the example.

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered, but I found this article also good for explaining why Autowired dependencies are null:

https://www.moreofless.co.uk/spring-mvc-java-autowired-component-null-repository-service/